# I would like to connect a html flie with a php file

Tags: php, html, raspberry-pi

Hello I have an html that is basically the command for a remote control car when you press the go forward button a 1 is sent which has to receive a php file and in case 1 execute a python script that would move the engines forward.
This is the part that conects the html with the php

```
$(this).click(function(){
   console.log("estado: "+estado);
    $.ajax({
        data:{valor_estado: estado},
        url:'procesa.php',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(response){
            //alert("Salida: "+response );
        }
    });
  });

});
```

And the php file is

```
<?php
$valor_estado=$_POST['valor_estado'];
switch ($valor_estado) {
    case 1:
        exec('sudo python /var/www/html/py/avanza.py');
        break;
    case 2:
        exec('sudo python /var/www/html/py/izquierda.py');
        break;
    case 3:
        exec('sudo python /var/www/html/py/derecha.py');
        break;
    case 4:
        exec('sudo python /var/www/html/py/retrocede.py');
        break;
    case 5:
        exec('sudo python /var/www/html/py/para.py');
        break;
    default:
        exec('sudo python /var/www/html/py/para.py');
        break;
}
?>
```

I am new in Raspberry and I don't know why this doesn't work

Comment: the last `});` in your ajax code is superfluous, typo...

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code should be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").click(function(){
   let id = $(this).val();
   console.log("estado:"+id);
    $.ajax({
        data:{valor_estado: id},
        url:'test.php', // if not in same directory or workstation use http://ip/test.php
        type:'POST',
        success: function(response){
           alert("Salida: "+response );
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Buttons:</h1>
<button class="btn" value="1">[1]</button>
<button class="btn" value="2">[2]</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you need a web server ([Nginx](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/nginx.md) or [Apache](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md)) for executing PHP from URL or use built-in PHP's web server in the command line by running this command in code directory:

```
sudo php -S 0.0.0.0:80
```

After that, you can send remote data by clicking the buttons. Your PHP code should work if it has the right permission for executing python scripts.

I suggest you use `PHP -S` for debugging and then use a real web server like Nginx or Apache.